# Way to have subdirectories in umbrella project

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Does anyone know if there is a way to make umbrella projects look in subdirectories of the apps_path?

I've poked around the docs a bit but have had no luck.

Here is an example structure of what I want.

```
mix.exs (for umbrella, apps_path: modules)
modules/
    protocols/ (subdirectory)
        blah/
            mix.exs
    other/
        blah_two/
            mix.exs
    phoenix_app/
        mix.exs
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look for _what_?

Comment: sorry - look for modules.  ex: protocols/foo and protocols/bar

Comment: I believe it’s an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve? Why do you think it should be an umbrella? What is wrong with Elixir packages?